# How to pickle.load a string and then file.write it?

Tags: python, utf-8, pickle, codec, cyrillic

The obvious way returns an exception.

I try this:

```
import codecs
import pickle
with codecs.open('1.pickle', 'r') as new:
    somebiglist = pickle.load(new) #a big list with inner lists
for iter in somebiglist:
    print 'Some cyrillic string. %s' % iter[0]

#Prints out to console perfectly

with codecs.open('anyfile.txt', 'w', 'utf-8') as anyfile:
    for iter in somebiglist:
        anyfile.write('%s \n' % iter[0])
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/PythonProject/1.py", line 38, in <module>
    anyfile.write('%s \n' % iter[0])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0412' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I make the same string inside the script (without loading from pickle file) it is written to file without any problems.

Where is encoding disappears? I tried all the variations of 'encoding', 'utf-8' and 'wb/rb' options.

Comment: What does the information in `1.pickle` look like? Or better yet, how was it built?  Was it a list of lists (of some cyrillic strings) that was written by `pickle.dump` or was it just written with a `file.write`?

Comment: @Mike McKerns It was pickle.dump'ed

Comment: Did you try without 'utf-8'?

Comment: @Banana i did. and tried both with and without 'utf-8' codecs when i was writing '1.pickle'

Comment: Try `anyfile.write(u'%s \n' % iter[0])`.

Comment: @martineau Same thing again... I think there's a problem in my usage of 'codecs' module...